# Calling MPI_send MPI_recv from a fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran, mpi

is it possible to call the MPI_send and MPI_recv commands inside a subroutine and not the main program? I have written a minimal program for what I am trying to do. It is compiling fine but it is not working. The program just hangs in the "sendrecv" subroutine. Any ideas how can I do it?

main.f

```
  program   main

  implicit none 

  include  'mpif.h'

  integer me, np, ierror

  call  MPI_init( ierror )
  call  MPI_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, me, ierror )
  call  MPI_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, np, ierror )

  call sendrecv(me, np)

  call mpi_finalize( ierror )

  stop
  end
```

sendrecv.f

```
  subroutine sendrecv(me, np)

  include 'mpif.h'

  integer np, me, sender, tag
  integer, dimension(mpi_status_size) :: status

  integer, dimension(1) :: recv, send

  if (me.eq.0) then

     do sender = 1, np-1
        call mpi_recv(recv, 1, mpi_integer, sender, tag,
 &           mpi_comm_world, status, ierror)

     end do
  end if

  if ((me.ge.1).and.(me.lt.np)) then
     send(1) = me*12

     call mpi_send(send, 1, mpi_integer, 0, tag,
 &        mpi_comm_world, ierror)
  end if

  return
  end
```

Comment: As an alternative to debugging your own code, you could try using the library `mpi_sendrecv` routine.

Comment: Couple of observations. First your using mpi_int rather than mpi_integer, mpi_int is what you use in C. Secondly your uninitialized variables - in particular tag not being set may be the problem here.

Comment: Sorry for those mistakes. I edited them. But still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: You still did not set the value of tag, you only switched from implicit to explicit typing. You should initialize all variables, that are not intent out.

Comment: oh! my mistake. Thanks, its working now after I have initialized the tag variable. Sorry for my negligence